# How to loop icons in flutter?

Tags: loops, flutter, widget, icons

I have list of data and I want to declare each list to has a icon... whenever user click the icon.. the icon will change to another icon.. here is the code

```
ListView.builder(
              itemCount: data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(
                      leading: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState((){
                             match=true;
                           });
                        },
                        child: 
                         match
                             ? Icons.check
                             : Icons.error
                      ),
                      title: Text(data[index],),
                      subtitle: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Text("subs here.."),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              }),
```

from that code.. after user click first icon... all the icon inside list view builder has changed.. is there a way to change icon only for icon that I have clicked (not all icon)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can maintain the index of selected list widget which you did for match variable

```
                     setState((){
                             match=true;
                             _index = index;
                             });
```

Then add a condition like

```
           match && _index == index
                     ? Icons.check
                     : Icons.error
              ),
```

Comment: I like this answer. It is pretty optimized. This should be marked the correct answer.

Comment: Hi.. wait..I will try it and let you know the result soon

Comment: it works very well like what I want.. thank you very much for your help :D

Answer (score 2):

Separate the list item in its own stateful widget so every listitem can hold its own state.

```
class ListItem extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListItemState createState() => _ListItemState();
}

class _ListItemState extends State<ListItem> {
  bool match = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              match = true;
            });
          },
          child: Icon(match ? Icons.check : Icons.error)),
      title: Text(
        "asd",
      ),
      subtitle: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Text("subs here.."),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

add the widget to the ListView

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListItem();
            }
```

Comment: Hi.. I will try it and let you know the result